# can't create a new directory using mongoose and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Like the title entails.
I'm trying to make an application that when i put in certain info, it creates a link using mongoose _id. and express's app.get what i don't get is that to be able to join that directory i have to reload the whole server, which for the users and my sake a i don't want to do.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);
var router = express.Router();
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    var ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/NEW_DB1");
console.log("Connection to database has been established");
var collectedData = new mongoose.Schema({
    ipAddress: String,
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: false
    }
});
var collectionOfData = mongoose.model("dataType", collectedData);
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    socket.on("name", function (e) {

        var ip = socket.request.socket.remoteAddress;
        var dataBase = mongoose.connection;
        var Maindata = new collectionOfData({
            ipAddress: ip,
            name: e
        });
        Maindata.save(function (err, Maindata) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.dir(Maindata);

            }
        });

    });
});
app.get("/mix", function (req, res) {
    collectionOfData.find(function (err, data) {
        res.send(data);
    });
});
collectionOfData.find(function (err, data) {
    data.forEach(function (uniqueURL) {
        app.get("/" + uniqueURL._id, function (req, res) {
            res.send("<h1>Hello " + uniqueURL.ipAddress + "</h1><p>" + uniqueURL.name + "</p>");

        });
    });
});
http.listen(10203, function () {
    console.log("Server is up");
});
```

So what i'm trying to do is make it so i don't have to reload the whole server, and i'm able to just join the created directory when it's done being loaded.

figured i should put a quick example:

```
localhost:10203/55c2b2f39e09aeed245f2996
```

is a link a user just created the long

```
55c2b2f39e09aeed245f2996
```

is the effect of the _id, but when the user try's to connect to that site it won't work until i reload the server and obviously i'd like to avoid that haha.
I have a index.html file, but all that has is a socket.emit that sends "name" to the server

Comment: please, i've been searching the whole internet for an answer to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    var ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});    

app.get('/:uniqueURL', function(req, res){
    var id = req.params.uniqueURL;
    res.send("Your requested id : " + id);
})
```

Try to use this above. 
You are creating fix get path inside collectionData.find. That is the problem. So each time you have to reload the server by restarting.

Comment: I'm still confused? try this where exactly?

Comment: app.get("/", function (req, res) {
        var ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    });    
    
    app.get('/:uniqueURL', function(req, res){
        var id = req.params.uniqueURL;
        res.send("Your requested id : " + id);
    })

Comment: Cool this seems to work, but how would i go by implementing my other variables like ipAddress and name?

Comment: Once you get id, make a DB call   collectionData.findOne( { "_id" : id } , function(err, data) {   // use data. ipAddress and data.name }  );

Comment: thanks will do. will the data show up readable for people? or will it be in JSON format? Im kinda new to Mongoose and MongoDB. if you haven't noticed it haha

Comment: Nvm it does. I can't possibly thank you enough man, I've been looking for an answer to this question for about 7-9 hours.

Comment: I would recomment to use `req.ip` instead `req.connection.remoteAddress`